# Android-"Error:(44, 22) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/searchIcon')."

Tags: android, imagebutton

I added a imagebutton in my application but when i run my app it show the error
like

```
Error:(44, 22) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/searchIcon').
```

Here is my Xml code

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/searchIcon"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
```

I added the **searchIcon** image in the drawable folder eventhough i getting the error.
ThankYou

Answer (score 1):

Resource names should not contain any capital letters. Rename your drawable to ic_search (to comply to naming standards as well).

Answer (score 1):

You can't use uppercase in resource name, so you need to change it to something like this:

```
search_icon
```

Related question:
[Why is it not possible to use uppercase in naming resources in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15320951/why-is-it-not-possible-to-use-uppercase-in-naming-resources-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Resources name should not be in Uppercase letters 
You can chhange to this

> search_icon